# python-sphinx autodoc import not possible until runtime. workaround?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, odoo-8, python-sphinx

I am trying to use Sphinx to document an Odoo project and I'm getting a failure when using autodoc, because the import is not possible until runtime. Let me break it down:

1. There is at least 1 module in the repository that needs to import a constant from another module.
2. Because there is no **init** at the project root, for this to work, the import is not:

   from [module_2].models.whatever import whatever
3. Instead, it has to be:

   from openerp.addons.[module_2].models.whatever import whatever

This is because odoo gathers all the modules from different addons paths into one pool at runtime and any module can import from a previously loaded module (order depends on dependencies).

Because the import mentioned above is impossible for Sphinx to resolve, I am getting a "cannot import name ..." error when I try to build. I could remove that import, copy paste the constant from the other module and that would be that, but mutilating the code and implementing a bad practice just for the sake of autodoc seems iffy and I've only started documenting this huge project, so I have no idea how many more of these will come up (I recall at least 1 more of my modules does this). What would be the best way to go about this?

By the way, the traceback is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 657, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "account_analytic_default_segment/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "account_analytic_default_segment/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import account_analytic
  File "account_analytic_default_segment/models/account_analytic.py", line 7, in <module>
    from openerp.addons.account_analytic_policy.models.analytic import USAGE
```

A bit more on the structure, the project sits in a directory included in the addons_path of the Odoo configuration, which is completely separate from the Odoo directory. At runtime, all the addons paths get included (think of it as kind of a symlink). But before runtime, they are unrelated. I've fixed the problem with other "from openerp ..." imports by including Odoo in the PYTHONPATH, but this does not resolve the problem when importing from another module in the project, because they do not see each other before runtime and during runtime they are only accessible from the Odoo addons pool.

Comment: Is this module very important for your documentation? If not, you can add it to the Sphinx mock list, and it will ignore it. The con is that you will not be able to reference anything from this module in your docs

Comment: Well, the requirement is to have coverage of every module. How would you suggest using it? I tried adding ['openerp.addons.account_analytic_policy.models.analytic'] in hopes that it would treat every import from that module valid, but it doesn't seem to work that way, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. What I need essentially is for sphinx to treat the "from openerp.addons.account_analytic_policy.models.analytic import USAGE" line as valid.

Comment: I suggest writing in the conf.py script in your documentation directory the following lines: `MOCK_MODULES = [openerp.addons.account_analytic_policy.models.analytic]` and then `sys.modules.update((mod_name, Mock()) for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES)`

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. Still getting an ImportError. I've actually given up and decided to make changes for documentation purposes only and leaving comments to explain why the master branch code differs from the source in the documentation. Odoo themselves say that these imports are not a good idea, but they are the only choice (apart from copy paste'ing) when you need to use a constant or a method defined outside a class/model.

Comment: Note that what I wrote is an example in case that you only want to ignore that library. If the problem persist, that is probably because other libraries are causing problems. You can add all the libraries that you want to the mock list, i.e. `MOCK_MODULES = [library1, library2...]`

Comment: There is a special config variable for listing modules to mock. Did you try that? http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_mock_imports.

Comment: @Jalo I realize that, I did use the correct library and the error referenced that same library. Maybe it only works for 'import lib1' statements and not for 'import x from lib1'? Should I mock the x (which is a constant in lib1)?

Comment: @PauliusStundžia I am not sure, but you may try mocking lib1.x

Comment: @mzjn This resolves the import problem, but then no modules at all get autodoced. I'll see if I can figure out the problem.